# How to select multiple directories in apache2.conf

Tags: apache2

I have the following file structure:

```
/var/www
/var/www/subdirectory
```

I want to configure my apache2.conf with a  directive that applies to both `var/www` and all it's subdirectories and files.

`<Directory "var/www">` only applies to the parent directory.

`Direcotry "var/www/*/">` only applies to the subdirectories.

**Clarification**

I am using https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache to try and configure apache2.conf. I therefore want all the changes to apply to every public file served (root dir and all other files).

When I read https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache, I get the understanding that `var/www` should apply to all subdirs, however the `Options -Indexes` rule clearly does not work (subdir indexes are visible). When I try `var/www/*` the indexes no longer show, but other rules are not applied to the root dir.

I can isolate this issue:

```
<Directory "var/www/*">

    <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
        Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Disables listing of subdirs, whereas:

```
<Directory "var/www">

    <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
        Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Does not.

How can I apply the directive to both, and all included files?

Comment: Do you want to include the files and directories like "www.domain.com/subdirectory/file-in-subdirectory" or do you want everything in the root-dir ("www.domain.com/file-in-subdirectory")?

Comment: I want to include both. Please see update.

Comment: according to the apache documentation: `<Directory> Description: Enclose a group of directives that apply only to the named file-system directory, **sub-directories**, and their contents.` Your directiev already includes the subdirs...

Comment: @chaos Yes: that's my question.

Answer (score 0):

To assign global options like `Options -Indexes` you can insert them in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/autoindex.conf`, or perhaps more elegant: create a file `/etc/apache2/conf.d/autoindex` with your modifications. Don't forget the `IfModule` directives before and after your options.